# How do you make an emergency water filter and purifier?

Tags: survival, water-purification

How do you make an effective water filter using the natural elements of the great outdoors?

Suppose your only source of water was dirty and questionable at best. How could you make it potable without having to boil it and using only what mother nature has to provide?

I've never made one before, but I imagine it involves sand to filter out the grits, and probably charcoal to absorb the nastiness, as well as a couple other layers for reasons; like herbs that may be effective in killing microbials or some other form of alchemy that will make it safer to drink.

How do you make your own water filter when you're in a desperate situation?

Comment: **Related:** [What are the different methods to purify water?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-are-the-different-methods-to-purify-water), but making your own filter isn't one of the answers.

Comment: **Also Related:** [What backwoods trick to get pure water produces the most safe water?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/what-backwoods-trick-to-get-pure-water-produces-the-most-safe-water?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I want to filter the water, not distill it.

Comment: What level of filtration are you comfortable with? Some virus' and something like mercury are very difficult to filter without nano filters which you can't produce without sophisticated equipment

Comment: Isn't this going to depend on what you mean by 'dirty' and what you think it's contaminated with?

Comment: @Liam, people drank water long before sophisticated equipment ever existed. I'm comfortable drinking water straight out of the creeks and streams. I've never used a water filter before, I'm just curious because of this question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13363/should-i-eat-when-i-dont-have-anything-to-drink-in-a-survival-situations?noredirect=1#comment31489_13363

Comment: @DJClayworth Don't think it really matters. If the water is dirty as filth, but it's the only liquid for miles, what can you do with it to stay alive? If the water is clear, and doesn't feel slimy, then I'm probably going to drink it straight.

Comment: @ShemSeger, [totally agree](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5106/do-you-need-to-purify-all-mountain-water-sources). Just trying to get a feel as to what your after

Comment: even when filtering, it is advisable to heat water on a rolling boil for 4 minutes to try and remove any nasties that weren't filtered out

Comment: @Chris, depends who you talk to. I've also heard that as soon as water comes to a boil everything in it is dead. And we're supposing you don't have anything to boil water in here.

Comment: @ShemSeger that sounds like a challenge! A bit of research has led me to believe that dropping hot rocks into a watertight container is the way forward... for a water tight container in the wilderness see plastic bottles on the shoreline (boo), a hollowed out and charred piece of wood, a piece of bamboo, broad leaves shaped using twigs, birch bark or you could go the whole hog and dig up some clay and throw it in the fire.

Comment: @ChrisJ I've asked another question here: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/how-do-you-boil-water-without-a-pot

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Charcoal means you *had* a fire. It could come from a tree burnt by lightning strike, forset fire, or an old found camp fire. Either way, you can't boil dirt out of water. Neither can you boil water without an adequate container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Gravity Filters

### Cone Filter

Much like Charlie's gravity filter in a bottle, this filter is essentially the same, only using a cone of tree bark in place of the bottle, and using extra filtration layers instead of a coffee filter or bit of cloth:

[image]

[image]

### Tripod Filter

Using a shirt, or bag with a hole in the bottom, or whatever bits of material you can spare, you can set up a tripod filter as shown below:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Images: [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/258253359854893556/), of all places...</sup>

These filters appear to only be effective at cleaning the water of dirt and debris, boiling the water is still recommended for purifying the water and killing anything that might make it through your filter, though any poisons should be mostly absorbed by the charcoal.

What remains to be discovered is what could potentially be used in either of these systems to purify the water as much as possible without boiling.

---

### Filtration Layers

The following are layers you can include in your filter, and what they accomplish:

- **Grass:** Filters out floaties, larger debris, and works as a permeable layer to support sand and charcoal.
- **Pebbles:** Remove larger grits like sticks, leaves, gravel, small stones, etc.
- **Gravel:** Permeable layer that packs well, good base layer for sand and charcoal, also filter larger particles.
- **Sand:** Filter out smaller grits, sand, etc.
- **Ground Charcoal:** Filter out finest particles, as well as some toxins/poisons (absorbed by carbon), will lose it's ability to absorb toxins with use.
- **Twigs:** Plug bottom of cone filter so other layers don't pour out bottom.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I have found for a very basic set up with a cheap water bottle. The water will be pored through the top through gravel, sand, charcoal and finally either a screen or another mechanism like a hankerchief to prevent the filtering substances from getting into the water.

Like this,

```
|    |
|GGGG|
|SSSS|
|CCCC|
 |00|
```

- | = Water bottle edge
- G = Gravel
- S = Sand
- C = Charcoal
- 0 = Screen or cloth

For more information I would suggest this [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Water-Filter-out-of-a-Waterbottle/?ALLSTEPS).

Comment: Screen and cloth are usually not considered "what mother nature has to provide" nor is a water bottle.  Maybe replace the water bottle with a bark cone and the screen with moss.

Comment: I'd add to this, at least in Europe, a layer of sphagnum moss, which has natural disinfectant properties. Be aware, however, that it's a protected species in some countries.

Comment: @filth I'm pretty sure human beings count as a protected species as well. All the rules go out the window when it comes to preserving your own life.

Comment: @JamesJenkins You may not have a bottle on you, but at the very least I would hope you're wearing clothing, a bit of cloth off your shirt would suffice here I imagine. But it would be difficult if you didn't at least have a bottle.

Comment: Just a reminder, for those who night be inclined to idly practice making such a filter. Many exceptions to the rules are permitted in survival situations, but are frowned upon when used merely for fun or for practice.

Comment: @ShemSeger you know they have entire TV program/series about people in the outdoors without clothing?  [Naked and Afraid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_and_Afraid) Realistically you might be separated from your clothes in any number of scenarios, if you are diving with only a wet suit, or drying your clothes after a incident and become separated from them.

Comment: when using something like this, I've been advised to run it through a few times as the more saturated it becomes the more efficient it will be

Answer (score 1):

Define dirty. The question says potable. The stuff that will hurt you requires very fine filtration that I don't think is feasible using natural elements.  Filters for protozoan cysts and bacteria typically filter to 0.2 microns

Yes you can filter larger particulate matter (e.g. dirt) but that is not (typically) the dangerous stuff.

Is Water Treatment Even Necessary?
Q: Why do I need to treat water in wilderness areas?

A: Regardless of how pure water may look, any water source on the planet could be tainted with microscopic waterborne pathogens—disease-causing pests that, if ingested, could cause severe diarrhea, cramps, vomiting and fever.

Recent research, though, suggests that wilderness water at higher elevations is much cleaner than previously believed. Some experts argue that the blame for intestinal infections is more often traceable to preexisting conditions and lax sanitation, particularly unwashed hands.

Q: What's in wilderness water that can affect me?

A: Three groups of waterborne critters are most commonly linked to water-related illness:

- Protozoan cysts (Cryptosporidium parvum, Giardia lamblia). Tiny (1 to
  300 microns; 1 micron = one-millionth of a meter).
- Bacteria (Escherichia coli, or E. coli, Salmonella, Campylobacter
  jejuni, Yersinia entercolitica, Leptospira interrogans and many
  others). Very tiny (0.1 to 10 microns).
- Viruses (hepatitis A, rotavirus, enterovirus, norovirus, Norwalk
  virus). Exceptionally tiny (0.005 to 0.1 micron). Viruses are rarely
  found in North American wilderness waters. Only purifiers (not
  filters) eliminate viruses.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There's nothing in this answer about making a filter, or purifier.

Comment: @ShemSeger The question states  potable.  "How could you make it **potable** without having to boil it and using only what mother nature has to provide?"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_water   Clearly I feel that pointing out it is not realistic is an answer.  If you feel differently then fine.

Comment: This *does* answer the question and is the right answer. There is no easy way to make safe potable water using resources available in the forest without boiling it. You can make the water look cleaner and maybe extract some contaminants with the filtration system described in the other answers, but you can't eliminate pathogenic protozoa, bacteria and viruses.